# Derivative of the Klein j-invariant

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, modular-forms

To prove that the field of meromorphic functions on $X(1)$ is generated by the Klein j-invariant, we need to show that the derivative of $j(\tau)$ does not vanish. (It only has simple zeroes).

But I don't know how to prove this. In Fred Diamond and Jerry Shurman's book "A First Course in Modular Forms", page 73, they just say that $j'(\tau)$ does not vanish.

Comment: Actually, to prove that the field of meromorphic functions on $X(1)$ is generated by $j$ it is enough to show that $j$ defines an isomorphism of Riemann surfaces $X(1)\to \mathbb P^1(\mathbb C)$. This is showed exactly at page 73 of the book you quoted. Also, what do you mean that $j(\tau)$ does not vanish? Do you mean that it is not constantly $0$ or that it has no zeroes?

Comment: @Ferra I mean it doesn't have a zero.

Comment: That happens because $j$ has a simple pole at $\infty$ and no other poles. Thus, $j'$ has a double pole at $\infty$ and no other poles. But $j'$ is a meromorphic $1$-differential on $\mathbb P^1(\mathbb C)$, and therefore it has degree $-2$. This shows that $j'$ cannot have any zero.